# Closing background Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

when i'm on the MainActivity in my app then press the setting menu in the action bar a new fragment is opened..there are two problems here

1- when i'm on the setting fragment then i press the multi-tasking button i found two windows for my app not one..the MainActivity and the settings

2- if i press the setting window when i'm still on multi-tasking window then press the back button it should take me to MainActivity instead it closes the app.

**So now what i want to do is**

1- close the MainActivity from the background once i open settings

2- if i press multi-tasking button and choose settings window in my app then press back it takes me to the MainActivity not close the whole app.

here is how i defined my activities in manifest file

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
       >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Settings"
        android:label="@string/settings_title"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.android.bee.MainActivity"/>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".Notifications"/>
</application>
```

hope the image helps visualizing it..thanks alot
[image: this is what happens when i press tthe multi-tasking button after i open settings from MainActivity]

Comment: It's hard to said it it you didn't show us how Activities are defined in AndroidManifest and how did you start it ... also do you know about "android:noHistory" attribute?

Comment: i added the code from manifest file..what i know about noHistory attribute that the user won't be able to back to that activity which i don't  want to do..i want the user to be able to go back to MainActivity from Settings..i'm beginner though so i might be getting it wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` attribute.

Comment: Yup that fixed it all..i was adding it as part of code to serve another purpose but turned out i don't need it..thank you :)